# How can I use a SceneKit Mesh in RealityKit?

Tags: scenekit, arkit, mesh, realitykit

I have [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/) code that generates 3D Meshes stored as [SCNGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry) objects:

```
geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, normalSource, texCoordSource], elements: elements)
```

I am porting my code to to use [RealityKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/). To my amazement I can not find any kind of adapter or converter so I can use SceneKit meshes in RealityKit; e.g., create a [MeshResource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshresource) from a `SCNGeometry` object with the goal of creating a [ModelEntity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/modelentity).
The [Model I/O framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio) does not mention RealityKit:

> "Model I/O can share data buffers with the MetalKit, GLKit, and
> SceneKit frameworks to help you load, process, and render 3D assets
> efficiently."

What about RealityKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also was unable to find any automated tool to port an app from SceneKit to RealityKit.  I had to do it manually.  Using the most recent version of RealityKit (from WWDC2023), here's my code for generating a Tetrahedron View:

```
struct Tetrahedron: View {
    var tetrahedronEntity = TetrahedronEntity()

    var body: some View {
        let modelEntity: ModelEntity = tetrahedronEntity.createModelEntity()

        RealityView { content in
            modelEntity.scale = [ 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 ]
            content.add(modelEntity)
        }
    }
}

final class TetrahedronEntity: Entity {
    let vertices: [SIMD3<Float>] = [            // A tetrahedron has 4 vertices.
        SIMD3( x:  1.0, y: -1.0, z:  1.0 ),     // vertex = 0
        SIMD3( x:  1.0, y:  1.0, z: -1.0 ),     // vertex = 1
        SIMD3( x: -1.0, y:  1.0, z:  1.0 ),     // vertex = 2
        SIMD3( x: -1.0, y: -1.0, z: -1.0 )      // vertex = 3
    ]

    let counts: [UInt8] = [3,3,3,3] // A tetrahedron has 4 faces, each with 3 corners
    let indices: [UInt32] = [
        0, 1, 2,                    // indices to vertices array for face = 0
        1, 0, 3,                    // indices to vertices array for face = 1
        2, 3, 0,                    // indices to vertices array for face = 2
        3, 2, 1,                    // indices to vertices array for face = 3
    ]

    func createModelEntity() -> ModelEntity {
        var meshDescriptor = MeshDescriptor()
        meshDescriptor.positions = MeshBuffers.Positions(vertices)
        meshDescriptor.primitives = .polygons(counts, indices)
        let mesh: MeshResource = try! .generate(from: [meshDescriptor])
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)
        let modelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        return modelEntity
    }
}
```

where I used the more-general .polygons primitive type (instead of the more-specific .triangles) as guidance for creating other polyhedrons.

Unfortunately, this updated version of RealityKit is currently only supported by visionOS, so you will have to run your Xcode app on a Vision Pro Simulator.

Comment: Thanks! I am surprised there is no `.triangle_strip` primitive.

Comment: Why not make `TetrahedronEntity` a subclass of `ModelEntity` and use an `init` constructor instead of using a `createModelEntity` method?

Comment: @wcochran, as you know, SceneKit has the following built-in SCNGeometry element primitives: triangles, triangleStrip, line, and point.  But RealityKit has only the following MeshDescriptor primitives: polygons, triangles, and trianglesAndQuads.  I am waiting for them to (hopefully) add line (or tube) and triangleStrip for connecting vertices.

Comment: @wcochran, thank you for your suggestion.  You are right.  If all I wanted was an entity for the entire tetrahedron then using an init constructor would be the way to go.  But I want more flexibility.  I plan to add a ```createEdgeEntity``` method and a ```createFaceEntity``` method so that I can separately modify the colors of the edges and faces.  Using the method construct seems to me to provide both flexibility and encapsulation.